# How to replace a matched group value with Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, connection-string

I would like to modify the value of the "data source" component in a connection string. I'm thinking of the following solution:

Using this regex pattern:

```
"data source\=((\w|\-)+?\\{1}\w+?)\;"
```

I can obtain the following string matches:

```
Match.Groups[0].Value = "data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;"
Match.Groups[1].Value = "MY-PC\SQLEXPRES"
```

So in the connection string firstly I would like to find the part matching with the "data source=something;", and secondly replace just the "something" in the connection string. How to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you insist Regex replacing, please note C# cannot modify a built string, you need to get a new string with the needed part replaced.

```
var connectionString = @"data source=MY-PC\SQLEXPRESS;";
var pattern = @"(data source=)((\w|\-)+?\\\w+?)\;";
var newConnectionString = Regex.Replace(connectionString, pattern, "$1" + "something");
Console.WriteLine(newConnectionString);
```

Comment: That was the solution I was looking for and figured out myself in the meantime. With Regex.Replace I just replaced the matched part to a created string that I created previously with String.Format("data source={0};", newSql);

Answer (score 1):

For most connection string types in .NET there should be a corresponding ConnectionStringBuilder class to handle this sort of thing. How are you connecting to your DB?

Comment: With EntityFramework. There is a connection string in the app.config. Thanks anyway, but the question is more to the Regex usage, not specifically to connectionstring-handling.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace it.

```
string dbSource = "data source=myserver\\sqlexpress";

int sLen = dbSource.IndexOf("=") + 1;
string getString = dbSource.Substring(sLen, dbSource.Length - sLen);

dbSource = dbSource.Replace(getString, "whatyouwantotoreplaceitwith");
```

Comment: That wouldn't do the trick as the connectionstring contains more equality sign.

Comment: @Pistaatortenesz that doesn't matter, indexOf will only return the position of the first '=' sign. My solution will work 100% of the time in this case, regardless of how many equals signs are in the string.

Comment: "metadata=", "provider=", "connection string=", all these precedes the data source in my connection string. But I also would like to modify Password and User Id as well... so the order doesn't count anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your matches further by using simple string.split with '=' character or if you like regular expressions see [MSDN Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(v=vs.110).aspx) Method