# How to replace words while keeping case?

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I have a string as such:

```
string myString = "String testing string replace"
```

I want to take that string and give the word **string** a style. So the final string would be:

```
myString = "<span class='myclass'>String</span> testing <span class='myclass'>string</span> replace"
```

How can I do that programmatically? So that both instances of the word **string** keep their case?

Comment: Look up regular expressions. Specifically, use a capturing group to capture your search word, then use a reference to that group during replacement. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984428/how-to-replace-a-matched-group-value-with-regex

Comment: code please? I am not very familiar with regular expression usage

Comment: Do you have to handle generic cases, or is your string well known?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
var myString2 = Regex.Replace(
  myString, 
  Regex.Escape("string"), 
  "<span class='myclass'>$0</span>",    
  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

The pattern is just the string you want to replace, escapes so if it had any characters in it that mean something to Regex (like a period) they match exactly. When a match occurs the whole match is stored in variable $0. This variable can be used in the replacement, so when we specify IgnoreCase it means that first match is on `String`, which means the replacement $0 is `String`.. the second match is on `string`

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = "String testing string replace";
string stringOut = "";
foreach (var word in myString.Split(new char[] { ' '}))
{
  stringOut += $"<span class='myclass'>{word}</span> ";
}
Console.WriteLine(stringOut);
```